# Using a cosine similarity does not work for any dataset

Tags: clustering, distance-functions, distance, similarities, euclidean

I have a clustering algorithm, where if I use an euclidian distance as similarity, it works well on any dataset. If I replace it by a cosine similarity (see my code bellow), it will give a degenerate results (will not work at all). Did I do an error in coding this cosine similarity or it is the cosine similarity that should by nature work only on some kind of data ?!

And by the way, this is a "similarity", is there any different between it and the "distance" ?

Here are example vectors from two datasets that I use. The second dataset may contain many repeated vectors:

Examples from dataset1: http://pastebin.com/6iYcqgWF

Examples from dataset2: http://pastebin.com/4MtLXwp7

Note: the square is just because the function is called under a root in the main program ..

```
// My squared  euclidean distance similarity 
float computeSqrDistance(vector<float> pos1, vector<float> pos2)
{
    float sum = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < pos1.size(); ++i)
    {
        sum += pow( (pos1[i] - pos2[i]), 2.0 );
    }

    return sum;
}


// My squared cosine distance similarity 
float computeSqrDistance(vector<float> pos1, vector<float> pos2)
{
    float sum0 = 0, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < pos1.size(); ++i)
    {
        sum0 += pos1[i] * pos2[i];
        sum1 += (pos1[i]*pos1[i]);
        sum2 += (pos2[i]*pos2[i]);
    }

    float similarity = sum0 / ( sqrt(sum1) * sqrt(sum2) );

    similarity = 1 - (acos(similarity) / M_PI);

    return (similarity*similarity);
}
```

Comment: This is a dot product, right? you're trying to find theta between the two given a . b = |a||b|cos(theta)?

Comment: You can step this through in a debugger to determine whether the code implementation is correct.

Comment: 1. Why are you squaring your putative cosine distance; 2. why the arccos?

Comment: @larsmans - I think the arccos comes from the way the [angular silimarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Angular_similarity) is calculated from the cosine similarity; the ang. similarity is a proper distance metric, while cosine similarity is not.  Not sure about the squaring

Comment: @Hans and all. the squaring is just because in the main program this function is called under the root sqrt .. The arccos is used to have a similarity within [0,1], I've defined this according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Comment: Would you please give us example vectors which give you " degenerate results"? The only problem I can see is you do not check if you have a zero-length vector.

Comment: @kol I've edited my post to add some example vectors from two datasets that I use.

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "works well" and "does not work at all"?

Comment: @gui11aume It means that the distance returned is not discriminent at all, different data are close to each other while similar data are far. The problem was that I'm returning the similarity instead of the distance. Now if I return distance = 1-(similarity*similarity), it works well.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse can I merge it to the one of Stats ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the end of the function you take the arccosine of the computed score.
Actually, according to the definition (see the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) page for example) you should not.

If you want the dissimilarity, I think you should just do

```
return (1 - sum0 / ( sqrt(sum1) * sqrt(sum2) ));
```

The similarity score will always be within $(-1,1)$, by direct application of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequalityhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). If you want it to be within $(0,1)$ you can take the square or the absolute value. Actually, given your input, the similarity should always be in $(0,1)$ because all your values are positive.

By taking the arccosine you get an angle in radian between $0$ and $2\pi$. The gain of taking the arccosine and dividing by $2\pi$ is null, plus it is not what most people will call the cosine similarity.

A distance satisfies the axioms of a distance:

1. $d(x,y)>0$ if $x\neq y$, and $d(x,x)=0$.
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
3. $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

The third is known as the triangle inequality. A dissimilarity satisfies only 1. and 2.

Comment: The arccos as described in the wiki article is just to make the similarity within [0,1]. Actually I have the same problem even if I don'use the arccos at the end. i.e. even if I just use `return (1 - sum0 / ( sqrt(sum1) * sqrt(sum2) ));`

Comment: Note that without the `arccos`, you don't need the `1-` part.

Comment: I've edited my post to add some example vectors from two datasets that I use.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you do not have an **all-0 vector** in your data set!

Because for this object, the distances will degenerate. I figure you might get either an exception or `NaN`.

Also make sure to *not* confuse similarity and distance. Similarity will be high for similar objects, a distance would be low. There are two common variants of inverting the cosine similarity to a "distance": either by taking 1-angle, the other is arccos(angle).

Be careful when using it as a "distance", as it clearly is not a proper metric. It is undefined for the 0 vector, it violates coincidence (vectors (1,1) and (2,2) have distance 0!) and it probably won't satisfy the triangle inequality either.

Comment: So what should I return instead of 1-angle, when I have an all-0 vector in my dataset ? because it is actually the case. And I have also sometimes some repeated data (same vectors).

Comment: All good points (+1)!

Comment: There is no sensible value for the point 0. Whichever you choose, it will misbehave in one situation or another. The most sensible value is actually `NaN` - not a number. Think of it: what is the angle between a vector x and 0? There is no angle. It's not 0, and it's also not infinity.

Comment: Do you mean that I can use this dissimilarity only if I do not have an all-0-vector in my dataset ? What should I do if I have it ?!

Comment: You can always preprocess your data set. For example, you can remove the 0 vectors, and process them differently.

Comment: Anyway, I think that the all-0-vectors do not have any signification in the dataset, so I can remove it and forget about it, right ? One data from this dataset is a bag of words from a document; if none of the considered keywords is found in a document, we will have an all-0-vector representing this document. So I'm not sure if this all-0-vectors need to create their own class/cluster.

Comment: The documents then essentially are "empty" in a bag of words model. How would you compute similarity to an empty document? Yeah, I'd just drop them in preprocessing already.

Answer (score 3):

I checked out the example vectors. The algorithm gives larger squared similarity for vectors in the same group:

```
v1, v2: 0.772201
v3, v4: 0.670776
```

I got somewhat smaller squared similarity for vectors in different groups:

```
v1, v2: 0.585961
v1, v3: 0.606588
v2, v3: 0.543307
v2, v4: 0.555077
```

I think your problem is that you would like to get distance, not similarity. Just modify the end of your second function this way:

```
float distance = 1 - similarity;
return distance * distance;
```

Comment: awsome, this works better ! I have some questions then to complete your answer:

1) What is the difference between the similarity and the distance here ?

2) Knowing that the function should return a squared distance, is it different if I do: `float distance = 1 - (similarity); return distance*distance;` instead of `float distance = 1 - (similarity*similarity); return distance;` as you suggested ?

Comment: Conceptually, squared similarity is the "opposite" of distance. 0 squared similarity means maximum distance, and a squared similarity of 1 means 0 distance. So I would use my formula above. Another option: float distance = 1 - abs(similarity); return distance;

Comment: but `1 - abs(similarity);` is the "distance", or the "squared distance" ? Because my function should return the squared distance. So I should return `pow( (1 - abs(similarity)), 2);` right ?

Comment: Sorry I have to go home now, I will write an answer in about an hour.

Comment: Ok. By the way, the function return "nan" (not defined) instead of 0, when we compute the distance between two same vectors (v1 and v1), because actually the value of similarity just after `float similarity = sum0 / ( sqrt(sum1) * sqrt(sum2) );` is not 1 but 1.000000263 for example. And moreover, sometimes I have a 0 vector (where all values are 0) so sum0 sum1 or sum2 may be 0 ! How can I have a cosine distance function that handle this cases ?

Comment: Yes, I realized this too. 1st I thought this is due to the limited precision of floats, but in some cases sum0/(sqrt(sum1)*sqrt(sum2)) was a bit larger than 1 even when I used doubles. The difference is much smaller due to the higher precision of doubles, but it's still present.

Comment: Let me think :) The ratio sum0/(sqrt(sum1)*sqrt(sum2)) is the cosine of the angle between the vectors, so it's in [-1, +1]. Its acos is in [0, pi], so similarity, that is, 1-acos(ratio)/pi is in [0, 1]. Its value is 0, if the vectors point into opposite directions; 0.5, if they are perpendicular to each other, and 1, if they point to the same direction. Distance can be calculated as 1 - similarity = acos(ratio)/pi, and you need to return its square. So you were right. I modified my answer.

Comment: In order to avoid the rounding problem you mentioned above, I would calculate the ratio, and force it into [-1, 1] before calling acos. For example, with std::max from <algorithm> you can do this: ratio = max(-1, min(ratio, +1));

Comment: And in case where I have an all-0-vector in my dataset, what should I return ? (a vector where all values are 0)